# Difficulty of Emulating an Embedded Device?

Tags: emulation, virtual-machine, embedded-linux, qemu

I just don't know where to start, completely ignorant in emulating devices but I have an embedded linux device and I need to see if it is possible to emulate it using Virtual Box or Qemu.

I don't know the version of the linux or the hardware it's running on.

Some questions though if they could be answered that would be great.

If I was able to open the device and find out the hardware such as processor and other peripherals would I be able to emulate the hardware?

If i could ghost the entire embedded memory would I be able to boot it with a correct configuration?

I know that it uses Redboot and some form of linux and it might be a Matsushita processor, is it possible to emulate that processor?

Is there anywhere you think I should start? such as tackling a similar project with an easier device? or any references that you guys would suggest?

As I said before I'm totally ignorant in emulation and thanks for your help.

Edit:
Thanks Chris for pointing the direction, going to go with an emulator layer for the I\O.

More questions:

I have another device that is an embedded touch screen running some form of embedded linux, was wondering if it was also possible to emulate the system with touch signals from a mouse? 
Just need a yes or no because concept of simulating what is going to be on the screen still eludes me with linux.

Comment: A lot depends on what your goals in emulating it are.  For example, if the goal is software development you can probably do a lot by building for a normal linux, and providing an emulation layer for the I/O only.  If your goal is reverse engineering, unpacking the image without running it may be enough.  There are emulation solutions for the more popular processor architectures at least, but that doesn't mean they will usefully run a kernel built for specific hardware until you get a console working (or learn to find the kernel message buffer in ram with a debugger)

Comment: It's for software development or more specific to testing.Thanks for answering my question.  Going to look into an emulation layer for the I/O since the embedded system is pretty much a network gateway kinda device.  Not sure how it specifically works anyways.     Another question though.   I have an embedded screen running linux that has a server pushing movies to it, is it possible to have a virtual display? or not. I'll try to elaborate in my post edit.

Comment: What is the purpose of emulating these devices? Generally you emulate when a particular device is not available. (ie You want to build applications for Android 4.0, but you only have an Android 2.3 device) If you have these embedded devices, why don't you just build your application, copy them to the device, and execute?

Comment: Of course you will not be able to build any applications for them until you at least know what architecture they are running. So if the only way to do that is open them up and examine the chips, that might be your first step.

Comment: The hardware that is needed for testing is very costly, so if i could find a way to emulate the hardware, it would be easier for my team to bug test the software we are working with.  But thanks for the tip, I might be able to open one of the units I have on hand and start from there.